# Does "waking" have to be followed by the preposition "up"? For example, "I saw it in my dreams, don't see it on waking"

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

Should waking be always followed by "up"?

For instance in this following example,

"I saw it in my dreams, don't see it on waking"

Is it incomplete without "up"?

There is a poem with a title "On waking" Also found a medical article which says

> Tiredness **on waking** can be a symptom of an underlying health condition

However most entries have "up" and hence the question

Comment: Have you done any searching to see if it's possible? Did you search for "on waking" to see if other people have used it?

Comment: yes, I did. There is a poem with a title "On waking" Also found a medical article which says, "Tiredness on waking can be a symptom of an underlying health condition" However most entries have up and hence the question

Comment: I think you can self answer.  There is some use of "on waking" in formal or poetic contexts, but most use is "wake-up"

Comment: @Ammu Great. I've added that info to your question. On this site, to avoid lazy, trivial questions, people asking questions are required to show they've already made a basic effort to answer the question themselves, so in future, please include that info when asking a question

Comment: @JamesK Have you come across " on waking" in poetry?

Comment: Maybe I haven't, but you have!

Answer (score 1):

I Googled:

> "on waking" -up

And found the following snippets in the first four pages:

> Confusion on waking or as to one's identity
> Caffeine-induced sleep disruption: effects on waking the following day
> DIFFERENTIAL DISRUPTION OF EXECUTIVE FUNCTION, ON WAKING FROM MORNING AND AFTERNOON NAPS, IN SLEEP RESTRICTED SUBJECTS
> Sudden Onset of Refusal to Eat on Waking After a Nightmare

They're all medical titles or descriptions, and show that "on waking" is correct, but is almost exclusively used in formal medical language.